# Got wrong result when using `taosRestful` to access TDengine

Tags: go, tdengine

I'm using Go connector `taosRestful` to access TDengine. I want to check databases and tables, so I execute :
db.Exec("show databases")
But I got an error "wrong result".
Can't taosRestful execute this statement?  Or is there another way to write it?

I Googled the question but got no answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use taos.Query() to execute a query command. taos.Exec() is for inserting.